# json data not breaking line on html list

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I'm loading data from a json file in which i plan to use on html list with links, i'm not sure if the problem is the how i wrote the json file or how i access the data in the file.

according http://jsonlint.com/ the json file is correct

the menu.json file

```
[
    {
        "opciones": {
            "oferta": [
                {
                    "tipo": "1001"
                },
                {
                    "tipo": "1002"
                },
                {
                    "tipo": "1003"
                },
                {
                    "tipo": "1004"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "opciones": {
            "demanda": [
                {
                    "tipo": "2001"
                },
                {
                    "tipo": "2002"
                },
                {
                    "tipo": "2003"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Here is how i try to fill the html list code:

```
    <html ng-app="App">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>test html</title>

   <script src="json_load_menu.js"></script>   <!--script que cargar archivo json-->
  <link rel = "stylesheet"   type = "text/css"   href = "./css/style.css" />  <!--css con colores de celdas -->
  </head>

<body ng-controller="menuCtrl">

<div class="container">

    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu"><a href="#" >{{menuOpcion.opciones.oferta}}</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu"><a href="#" >{{menuOpcion.opciones.demanda}}</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the result:

> - [{"tipo":"1001"},{"tipo":"1002"},{"tipo":"1003"},{"tipo":"1004"}]
>     *
>
>   - [{"tipo":"2001"},{"tipo":"2002"},{"tipo":"2003"}]
>       *

what is supposed to do:

> *1001
>   *1002
>   *etc
>
> *2001
>
> *2002

How to avoid this?

EDIT:i have tried

```
<ul >
        <li ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu"><a href="#" >{{menuOpcion.opciones.oferta.tipo}}</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0].opciones.oferta"><a href="#" >{{menuOpcion.tipo}}</a></li>
</ul>

<ul >
  <li ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0].opciones.demanda"><a href="#" >{{menuOpcion.tipo}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, now the list it's empty